# Location of services created in Automator

Tags: automator, services

Long-time ago i created a service in Automator, which still works.
But i want to change the code and it isn't located in either /Library/Services/ nor ~/Library/Services/ as they are both empty

Have i lost the source code or can i restore it otherwise?

Comment: Strange...  `~/Library/Services/` is the default location for new services created in Automator, and I just confirmed that myself by creating a new service.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As others have said, services are normally in one of the Library/Services folders (~/Library/Services, /Library/Services, and /System/Library/Services).  If just looking there doesn't turn it up, another option is to spy on what files are being opened when you invoke the service, with something like:

```
sudo opensnoop -n WorkflowService
```

... and then running the service, and looking through the results to see if you can spot the relevant file.  If it isn't an Automator-based service, you might have to leave off the `-n WorkflowService` (although you'll have a lot more irrelevant files to sort through because you'll be seeing *every* file anything in the entire OS opens).

Comment: `sudo opensnoop -n WorkflowService` didn't show anything at all and couldn't get any reasonable out of just `sudo opensnoop`

Comment: @Tyilo: I'm pretty sure that means it's not actually an Automator-based service.  Might it be provided by an application you have installed?

Comment: You were right! I thought i made it myself... Thank you very much!

Comment: I have gained 10 experience points and hit +1 against buggy processes having now learned `opensnoop`

Answer (score 12):

The location of the user created services is under:

```
~/Library/Services/
```

(tested Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.4)

other locations you get by entering following command in Terminal:

```
mdfind .workflow
```

Comment: still the same on 10.9.5 and when in doubt the mdfind does it.

Comment: This was it for me on El Capitan. Note that `/Users/<username>/Library` is a hidden and/or system directory, so you'll need to [activate the proper settings](http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/) to display it in Finder.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `~/Library/Workflows/`?

Comment: Doesn't exist either and also tried /Library/Workflows/

Comment: This is precisely where I found mine, automator scripts created on Mavericks, but running Yosemite now.

Answer (score 1):

***Edited to add***

Automator services are definitely supposed to be stored in `~/Library/Services`, based on my Googling. I just created a new service in Automator and it placed it there.

---

Perhaps `~/Library/Application Support/Automator/`

Alternately, when I last made a service I believe that I had to save it as an `.app` first, so you might search for apps.

Comment: The /Library/Application Support/Automator/ folder didn't exist, but ~/Library/Application Support/Automator/ did and was empty -.-'

Comment: @Tyilo Sorry, that's what I meant. Fixed my answer, even if it's wrong. :)

Comment: @Matthew Frederick Found all app files using @Austin command, and none of them matched my service title

Comment: @Tyilo I just checked my system and realized that I'd created an AppleScript app that I then used Automator to turn into a service, hence my .app suggestion. As a result both .app and .scpt files existed for it. Unless you did the same, my suggestion is no help.

Comment: @Matthew Frederick Don't have the .scpt file of it :s, but the service file thingy must be somewhere, else it wouldn't work

Comment: @Tyilo Have you tried the in-depth search @Austin suggested but for files ending with `.service`. A number of my services have this extension.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for `.workflow` in Spotlight to find all workflow files in your user folder.  The service will be called `Whatever the Service Name Is in the Services Menu.workflow`.

If you prefer the Terminal, this command will do the same thing, searching the current directory and all the folders underneath it:

`find ./ -name "*.workflow"`

EDIT: Corrected a small mistake in the Terminal command.  Apparently `-type f` doesn't work on `.workflow` files.

Comment: No result in Spotlight and the terminal command showed no results: 'tyilos-macbook:~ Tyilo$ cd /
tyilos-macbook:/ Tyilo$ sudo find ./ -type f -name "*.workflow"
Password:
find: .//dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: .//dev/fd/4: Not a directory'

Comment: @Tyilo Sorry, there was a typo in the Terminal command that I corrected.  Try it again, and if it doesn't find anything in your home directory (`~`), try running it from the system's root directory (i.e. enter `cd /` before running the find command).  *This will take a while, so be prepared to be patient.*

Comment: @Tyilo And of course, you can search the root folder in the GUI by opening `Macintosh HD` in Finder and typing `.workflow` into the search box.  (Check the `File Name` option instead of `Contents` for a faster search.)  The only disadvantage of this is that it won't search in hidden or system folders, but you probably won't need it to anyway.

Comment: @Austin My file wasn't between the files using `cd /` and `sudo find ./ -name "*.workflow" > ~/Desktop/services.txt`. I found two other folders which also could be a possible location, but they didn't contain the file. The locations were `/Library/Application Support/Apple/Automator/Workflows/` and `/System/Library/Services/`. I've uploaded the file here: http://cl.ly/6i1t

Comment: @Austin also tried with `sudo find ./ -name "*" > ~/Desktop/all.txt` and still no match

Comment: @Tyilo Perhaps the extension changed somehow?  Try searching for `sudo find / -name "The Exact Service Name Including Spaces.*"`  (Without the "dot", that should find it across your entire hard drive regardless of the folder from which you initiate the search.)

Comment: @Tyilo Any chance it would be on a network drive?

Answer (score 1):

The best way that I know to find workflows or anything else is to use the app: "EasyFind.app".  Unlike the Finder and Spotlight and even the Unix command-line, EasyFind.app can be configured to search everywhere, and it has a Unix-style pattern-matching capability.  For example "*.workflow" can be used to find any Service on your entire hard-drive.

Best of all EasyFind.app is free and legal.

[EasyFind.app](https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZContentLink.woa/wa/link?mt=11&path=mac/easyfind)

[image: Configuring EasyFind.app to find any Automator workflow (including services)]

INSTEAD of using extra programs you can run your Terminal and enter command:

```
mdfind .workflow
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on where EasyFind is able to find stuff but `/usr/bin/find` isn't?

Comment: @patrix I've been looking at /usr/bin/find again.  I believe that it will work, it's just that EasyFind.app is easier to use.

Comment: @patrix: The following command works OK for me: find ~ -name "*.workflow"  better than find ./ -name "*.workflow" which only searches the current directory.  From the command-line, it is really /usr/bin/locate that I don't trust.  It is faster, but the files have to be indexed before they can be found.  Also, I don't trust Finder > Finder nor Spotlight to find everything because they don't open up application bundles or the ~/Library folder which is not invisible in Mountain Lion.  So /usr/bin/find is OK, it's just that for me, I still prefer EasyFind.app because it's easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I found following ~/Library/Services/ does exist, on my 10.8 OSX.
But I can not see it with Finder, only from Terminal.

I aslo find this:
http://www.macworld.com/article/1161156/view_library_folder_in_lion.html
That explain it little better.

Answer (score 0):

If the Services of workflow is generated by system, It will located in "/System/Library/Services".

But if you workflow(services) added by yourself from Automator, it will located in "/Users/[your username]/Library/Services".

Answer (score 0):

It is a hidden folder:`/Macintosh HD/Users/<username>/Library/Services`. The best way to get there is either create a new service in automator and save it and follow steps below, or if you have one created already follow these steps:

- Open System Preferences > Keyboard and click the Shortcut tab.
- Find the service that you created
- Right click on the service and Open in Finder.

It will reveal the hidden folder.